# Why can I not create variables in React class components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Earlier, I ran `npx create-react-app my-app`. While experimenting with it, I realised that my editor was not allowing me to add any variables to the react class components! So, in the following ...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class CComponent extends React.Component {
    const foo = 'sdf'; // problematic

    render() {
        return <input type="text" value={this.props.name} />
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CComponent name="Bismillah" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

... The results end in a strange error that say something like 'const can only be used in a .ts file'. Thereafter, I tried changing it to `let` and `var` but none of them worked either. What's going on!?

Comment: Because that's not valid JS. If you want to add variables to a class, you can do so in the constructor and assign them to `this`, i.e. in the constructor: `this.foo = "sdf";` then access it via `this.foo`

Comment: JavaScript is different than Java. Variables are not first-class members in class components. You'll have to use `this` keyword to achieve that.

Comment: @MananJoshi Got it! Thanks.

Comment: define it like ```foo = sdf``` and use it like ```<input type="text" value={this.foo}/>```

Comment: @JuniusL. Oh... that's interesting? So I can not define a variable using `const` or `let` but I can do so directly without specifying the "privacy" level? Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either define inside state or inside render method like this

```
class CComponent extends React.Component {
       state={foo:'sdf'}
        handleClick=()=>{
         alert('Hey...Welcome to SO')
        }
        render() {
            return( 
                <>
                <input type="text" value={this.props.name} />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
                </>
              )
        }
    }
```

inside render

```
class CComponent extends React.Component {
            render() {
                const foo = 'sdf'; 
                return <input type="text" value={this.props.name} />
            }
        }
```

Comment: Aah, okay!. That's interesting.

Comment: Both of those are valid but I have a note: Inside the render the variable only works within the render. And the state is special; you update it with a function setState() and when the value changes React will update some of the DOM.

Comment: @SydneyY yeah, you are right but here he asked to define variables. answer depends on question.

Comment: Absolutely, like I said, you are right. 3 answers for 3 different cases

Comment: @Grateful if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar Is it possible to define functions within the class components?

Comment: @Grateful yeah, you can, check i created handleClick for button for example

Answer (score 0):

In a class you assign variables to the class with a constructor function:

```
class CComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.foo = "bar"; // 'this' is used within the whole class to refer to the class itself.
  }
  render () {
    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript class public field declarations don't use `const`, remove the `const`  and your code should work fine.

```
class CComponent extends React.Component {

   foo = 'sdf';

 //create a method
 getFoo = function() {
   return this.foo;
 }

  render() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.props.name} />
  }
}
```

[JS Classess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Okay, I can see how to create function now... BUt why can't I create one using the function variable statement? For instance, why can't I do `getFoo = func() { ... };`?

Comment: Huh!? It doesn't for me!

Comment: @Grateful Just do `getFoo() { return this.foo }`, that should do what you want.